# Filter javascript object array by string array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects, like this:

```
var companies = [
    { "name" : "Company 1",
      "logo" : "/logo.gif" },
    { "name" : "Company 2",
      "logo" : "/logo2.gif" },
    { "name" : "Company 3",
      "logo" : "/logo3.gif" } ];
```

I want to filter this array to get only values which have a name which exists in another array:

```
var myCompanies = [ "Company 1", "Company 3" ];
```

In this example, the data to be returned would be:

```
var companies = [
    { "name" : "Company 1",
      "logo" : "/logo.gif" },
    { "name" : "Company 3",
      "logo" : "/logo3.gif" } ];
```

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`$.grep()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) to get a new, filtered array, like this

```
var result = $.grep(companies, function(e) { 
               return $.inArray(e.name, myCompanies) != -1;
             });
```

[You can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/pnDyW/).  Note that this performs much better than a [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) loop, you can test it here: http://jsperf.com/each-vs-grep

Comment: Thanks for the jsperf link - I hadn't heard about it before and it's a really nice tool.  I added in a test case for $.map() at http://jsperf.com/each-vs-grep/4 (it's clearly the slowest of the three answers)

Answer (score 1):

By loop only..

```
var newArray = [];
$.each(companies, function(){
  if($.inArray(this.name, myCompanies) !== -1) newArray.push(this);
});
```

jQuery utilies are used here: [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) and [jQuery.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

Comment: You can do this, but note it's much more expensive (due to the extra scope creation for `this`), you can compare it to `$.grep()` here: http://jsperf.com/each-vs-grep

Answer (score 0):

This should to the job:

```
companies = $.map(companies,function(element){
  return ($.inArray(element.name,myCompanies)>-1?element:null)
}
```